# Move two discs freely and quickly on the underside of a surface?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

The discs must remain in flat contact to the surface at all times but you can assume no friction while pushing them about.

No using magnets from the other side of the surface, for all intensive purposes assume it is infinitely thick on the other side.

You must be able to move the discs "freely" meaning that normal robotic arms won't cut it due to getting tangled after moving each disc in a circle around the centre maybe once at most.

---

I imagine the answer could be very useful if there is one, I couldn't find one after scouring the internet for a few hours but a solution would open a few doors, especially when it comes to "omnidirectional treadmills", if you replace each disc with a vertical cylinder you could crudely mimic any terrain.

I hope this isn't too theoretical, apologies if it is, I do really think there are numerous practical applications though and for that reason any working answer at all would be useful.

---

Edit: Since it was apparently ambiguous, let me clarify, no using magnets, obviously if a solution uses a machine that has a magnet internally for some reason required for that machine to function then that's fine.

The surface is arbitrary, it could be any material within reason and cannot be changed, assume the area above the surface cannot be altered in any way.

---

Edit 2: My mistake, I completely forgot to mention the surface has a finite size, although the shape could be practically anything as long as no corridors thinner than the sum of both discs' radii are within it, assume it is convex if you cannot find a solution for concave, or just assume it is a rectangle!

Comment: It sounds like you have a particular application in mind. Without the specifics, this question is rather too broad. Please can you add some information about the real-world problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I gave an example of where it would be useful already, although I admit that example has slightly more lax requirements (due to feet being unable to move completely freely), do I need a real world use for me right now for it to warrant a solution? Because I can't think of one right now. I don't have a particular application in mind.

Comment: What about wireless robotic 'things', which are charged inductively as they go about their business, moving the discs, but not getting 'tangled', as you previously warned? Like the robots that moves shelves around in warehouses, but on a much smaller scale?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift ah, I completely forgot to say I had already thought of that but dropped it because of edge cases where both discs near an edge, which I just edited to mention that it is a finite surface because I forgot. If both are near an edge such that the robot1 is where the disc2 needs to go and disc2 is blocking the path robot1 needs to go in order to get out of the way for disc2 then it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that you have a lot of restrictions in mind, but you're asking us to play 20 questions to discover them. That's not a good way to ask a question here. Please do read the [help/dont-ask] and note in particular **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: It seems I decoded the problem implied: Provide concept of arbitrary 3D movement infrastructure to two weight-bearing platforms (weight limit: 1 person, sized for 1 foot) with restriction that no platform/infrastructure can appear above any platform. No dead zones / forbidden paths of motion (except for the restriction) are allowed. Application: Virtual reality floor of arbitrary terrain; user's foot motion is tracked, platforms follow and extend vertically to provide "floor" at intended height for each step.

Comment: @Shefeto - I hadn't noticed that it was only two discs, and was thinking of a solution for any number of discs. I'd imagined a remote-controlled-car type robot (with omni-wheels), that fell entirely within the diameter of the disc, such that the edge case that you described isn't an issue...

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] your question so that it tells us about the problem you're trying to solve, not about how to "fix" your solution.

Comment: @Wasabi I already said that I don't have a real world problem that needs this solution, I just thought it was an interesting engineering problem that MAY be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single robotic arm or other mechanism providing 2 degrees of freedom, to move one disc. Said disc is attached to the arm through an axis of a motor. The stator/chassis of the motor would attach to another arm with a linear actuator moving the other disc closer/farther (and the motor turning would change the angle relative to the first) - turning and extending/retracting in a plane that lies below the plane of movement of the robotic arm. You'll need a rotary slip ring connector to provide control/power to the stator and actuator.

Essentially, attach both one disc and the base of a second robotic arm (moving the second disk) to the end of the first robotic arm.

Comment: "If that's insufficient, put WAY more detail in your question" considering I already said it was frictionless yet you proposed a way to make it frictionless, and I made it pretty clear one shouldn't be using magnets. I fail to see how more detail would help if you didn't read what detail there was.

Comment: @Shefeto: You said one shouldn't use magnets ON THE OTHER SIDE. You also never specified the bottom side can't be adapted in any way. Magnets in discs and metal coating seem to meet these prerequisites.

Comment: if you add a metal coating then you're touching the coating and not the surface, since you're clearly trying to pick apart my question to teach me a lesson on asking good questions or something I've added some edits.

Comment: Also I gave an example of where it would be useful to have a solution, since your solution couldn't be used as a solution to my example that heavily implies if not explicitly labels it as not a solution does it not?

Comment: @Shefeto: I really don't see how discs (or cyllinders) attached to the *bottom* surface of untouchable infinitely thick plane would help in an omnidirectional treadmill. Are the users going to walk on the ceiling?

Comment: the discs would be replaced with hydraulic cylinders, their position would change and the lengths would change in order to become platforms beneath their feet that can move in response to trying to walk  to emulate the ground at that level etc. It was all I could come up with off the top of my head, I will admit it's not great or really applicable in the next 10 years but it does highlight a use.

Comment: Your new answer is excellent, I think it ticks all the boxes, thank you, trying to think of a solution to a "simple" problem like this was keeping me up at night (figuratively).

Comment: @Shefeto: "The area above the disc is reserved for other uses; no infrastructure can be placed there." No need to invent forcefields.

Answer (score 0):

Given your multi-edited question, this seems as reasonable an answer as any other: mount each disk on top of a blimp, thus providing the necessary anti-gravity force to keep the disk on the surface.  Use the blimp's guidance system (propellors, ailerons, etc) to move wherever you please.

Yes, this is absurd, but your scenario is unrealistic.

Comment: doesn't sound fast, certainly much less fast than the other user's accepted answer